# Set CORS on Windows Azure blob storage using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm attempting to set CORS properties on my Windows Azure blob storage account. I'm using an ASP.NET server to send the PUT request.

The server is sending back a Forbidden response, saying "*Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.*"

So it must be something in my authentication header. Here are the two functions I use to get the header.

```
public string GetWindowsAzureAuthenticationHeader(string verb)
{
    string stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n"
                                        + "\n" // content encoding
                                        + "\n" // content language
                                        + "\n" // content length
                                        + "\n" // content md5
                                        + "\n" // content type
                                        + "\n" // date
                                        + "\n" // if modified since
                                        + "\n" // if match
                                        + "\n" // if none match
                                        + "\n" // if unmodified since
                                        + "\n" // range
                                        + "x-ms-date:" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R") + "\nx-ms-version:2013-08-15\n" // headers
                                        + "/{1}\ncomp:properties\nrestype:service", verb, CloudConfig.StorageAccountName);

    return SignThis(stringToSign, CloudConfig.StorageAccountKey, CloudConfig.StorageAccountName);
}

private string SignThis(string stringToSign, string key, string account)
{
    string signature;
    var unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    using (var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
    {
        var dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
        signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
    }

    String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}:{2}",
        "SharedKey",
        account,
        signature);

    return authorizationHeader;
}
```

This is the controller action that sends the request. The _mediaFactory.GetWindowsAzureCors method returns the contents of an XML file with my CORS request.

```
var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_mediaFactory.GetWindowsAzureCors(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server));
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(CloudConfig.StorageAccountUri);

request.Method = "PUT";
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R"));
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2013-08-15");
request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
request.Host = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", CloudConfig.StorageAccountName);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", _mediaFactory.GetWindowsAzureAuthenticationHeader(request.Method));

request.GetRequestStream().Write(content, 0, content.Length);
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
    model.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
    model.Response = response.StatusDescription;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Off topic comment: if you're using .net code, is there a reason you're not using Azure storage client library for setting CORS and consuming REST API directly. Just curious.

Comment: Ignorance. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple.

First, add reference to Azure Storage Client library in your project. If you're using Nuget, the package you would want to install is [`WindowsAzure.Storage`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).

After that, the function which sets the CORS settings is [`SetServiceProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.setserviceproperties%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). Here's the sample code to do so:

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
            blobServiceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule(){
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() {"*"},
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() {"*"},
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Post | CorsHttpMethods.Put | ... Other Allowed Methods,
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() {"http://yourdomain.com", "https://yourdomain.com", "blah", "blah", "blah"},
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600,
            });
            blobClient.SetServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
```

Comment: Of course I insist on doing things the hard way. That's way better. Thanks Gaurav!