# Azure Blob Storage - CORS on container basis (not account basis)

Tags: azure, blob, cors, azure-blob-storage

This SO Post - [Set CORS on Windows Azure blob storage using ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596917/set-cors-on-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-asp-net) is very similar to what I want. But the only answer on it tells you how to setup CORS for an entire Blob Storage Account.

I want it so that only certain containers within my account have CORS enabled, not all containers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible with Azure Blob Storage. CORS rules are applicable on all blob containers in a storage account.

Comment: is this still the case? since 2014 @guarav

Comment: Yep, still the same :).